# Emacs calling unbound key sequence `C-c @` a "non-prefix key"

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys, outline-mode

Emacs won't let me bind `C-c @ TAB` to `outline-cycle` in `outline-minor-mode`. It complains "Lisp error: (error "Key sequence C-c @ TAB starts with non-prefix key C-c @") -- but `C-c @` is bound to nothing.

Some minimal code to reproduce this experience would be the following:

```
(outline-minor-mode)
(setq-local outline-regexp "-- [*]+")
(setq outline-minor-mode-cycle t)
```

At this point, by running `C-h k C-c @` you can verify that `C-c @` is bound to nothing. Moreover, if you go on to press `TAB`, you can see that `C-c @ TAB` *is* bound to something. So it's a perfectly good key sequence.

Now try to redefine what it is bound to:

```
(define-key outline-mode-map (kbd "C-c @ TAB") 'outline-cycle)
```

and, if your system behaves like mine, you'll get the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Emacs wont let me bind a key, tells me, "Key sequence C-z c starts with non-prefix key C-z"](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54782/emacs-wont-let-me-bind-a-key-tells-me-key-sequence-c-z-c-starts-with-non-pref)

Comment: "Emacs won't let me bind C-c @ TAB to outline-cycle in outline-minor-mode" -- but you're attempting to bind it in `org-mode-map` not in `outline-minor-mode-map`.

Comment: @phils You nailed it! Thank you! I just needed to rebind the right map, namely `outline-minor-mode-map`.

Comment: @Drew Thanks! That question is about a similar but different problem. It includes a lot of discussion of :bind, which (to my knowledge) I'm not using. The other suggestion involved unbinding keys, but that appears to be unnecessary. In that one the OP really needed to create a prefix. In my case it was that I was trying to bind a key using a prefix that was not available as a prefix for the mode-map I was trying to redefine, because in fact I should have been redefining a different one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is due to a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to edit the wrong mode map. `(define-key outline-mode-map (kbd "C-c @ TAB") 'outline-cycle)` was not working (let alone `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c @ TAB") 'outline-cycle)`, which I had written at some point). But `(define-key outline-mode-map (kbd "C-c @ TAB") 'outline-cycle)` works fine.

My confusion came from the fact that a prefix was not permitted in one mode even when it was available in another mode. I did not realize that. Apparently a prefix must be cleared for use on a per-mode-map basis, as described somewhat in [this related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54782/emacs-wont-let-me-bind-a-key-tells-me-key-sequence-c-z-c-starts-with-non-pref).

Answer (score 1):

`org-mode-map` has a keybinding for `C-c @` in it, binding it to `org-mark-subtree`. That makes it a non–prefix key indeed. You could delete that keybinding first, if you wanted to. Or you could bind it in `outline-mode-map` instead, which seems to go better with the rest of the code you quoted.

Comment: Thanks! That would make sense, except I'm in a haskell buffer, not an org one. I'm running the emacs code I quoted from a file ending in .hs. The mode line at the bottom of the screen reads "(Haskell Interactive VHL Outl (*) yas)". Haskell and Interactive are bout about Haskell, VHL means volatile highlights, (*) means beacon-mode and yas means yasnippet.